# ssh localhost Connection closed by ::1

Tags: macos, ssh, localhost, openssh

I generated id_rsa.pub and add it to authorized_keys. But when i do `ssh localhost`, the connection got closed right away `Connection closed by ::1`

output of

```
ssh -v localhost
```

> mymachine:~ xxxxxx$ ssh -v localhost OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1:
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for * debug1:
>   Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22. debug1: Connection
>   established. debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity
>   file /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public:
>   No such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
>   file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
>   file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 debug1: Enabling
>   compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string
>   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote
>   software version OpenSSH_6.9 debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.9 pat OpenSSH*
>   compat 0x04000000 debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'xxxxxx'
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com 
>   none debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
>    none debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY debug1:
>   Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
>   SHA256:BfO1TyMSGKv0C1OG0osGN7AEXfmYV43/xxxxxxxxxx debug1: Host
>   'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key. debug1: Found
>   key in /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:5 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT 
>   received debug1: Authentications that can continue:
>   publickey,keyboard-interactive debug1: Next authentication method:
>   publickey debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa
>   debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279 Connection closed
>   by ::1

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044958/ssh-localhost-closes-connection-after-successful-login